# How does the fundamental theorem of algebra follow from Weierstrass’s theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, general-topology, soft-question

Can anyone please explain to me how the fundamental theorem of
algebra follows from or is related to the Bolzano Weierstrass’s theorem?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.1459

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I came across that link too, but I would like an explanation in words, not pure algebra.

Comment: You want an explanation "in words" for a mathematical fact? Well, that's weird...and I even trying to dumb the basic proof down one has, imo, to rely heavily on mathematics.

Comment: @DonAntonio I just want to know how they are connected. This question is part of an assignment so I didn't come up with it myself. I just don't have a clue at all what they have in common.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) has your answer.

Comment: @JaycobColeman That's the wrong theorem.

Comment: @Potato Oops. The question did not [specify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_theorem) Bolzano-Weierstrass prior to Mhenni Benghorbal's edit.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there is a great connection between the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem (BWT) and the fundamental theorem of algebra (FTA). I will go over this paper and try to break it down. First, to state the theorems:

BWT: Every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a convergent subsequence. Note that for the purposes below, it can be stated that any continuous function $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{R}$ (where $\mathbb{D}$ is a closed and bounded disk) has a minimum on $\mathbb{D}$.

FTA: Every non-constant single-variable polynomial with complex coefficients has a minimum of one complex root.

This paper gives a proof of the FTA via BWT. I will go through the technical details if you like, but since you asked, I will give an overview of what was written.

The reason the BWT is used is because it avoids the use transcendental functions (analytic function that does not satisfy a polynomial equation) since their theory is far deeper than the FTA.

For the proof, the first step is to establish an inequality that bounds $0$ above and below by the imaginary and real parts of a given $\zeta$ to some power greater than or equal to $2$. THe power is a natural number excluding the origin. The proof is via the Binomial formula.

The idea of the proof is to introduce a polynomial with coefficients in the complex plane. Call this $P$. Multiply this $P$ with its conjugate $\overline{P}$. Take the limit as $|z|\to\infty$ to establish that $P\overline{P}$ has a global minimum at some point $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$.

By assuming $z_0=0$ we can write $P\overline{P}$ minus the same quantity evaluated at zero (which is clearly positive). Using the substitution $r\zeta$ (where $\zeta$ is a complex number and a positive scalar $r$) and analysing the cases for $k$ odd and even separately finished the proof.

Is this okay?